# WSL Ubuntu - making libfreenect - CYTHON_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND

Tags: python, ubuntu, cmake, cython, libfreenect2

I am trying to build `libfreenect` in WSL in Ubuntu. I'm currently facing a problem identified by this line:

```
/bin/sh: 1: CYTHON_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND: not found
```

at the end of this log:

```
endeavour@DZHPwindows:~/libfreenect/build$ make
[ 16%] Built target freenectstatic
[ 32%] Built target freenect
[ 35%] Built target freenect-wavrecord
[ 39%] Built target freenect_sync
[ 42%] Built target freenect-glpclview
[ 46%] Built target freenect-camtest
[ 50%] Built target freenect-glview
[ 53%] Built target freenect-regview
[ 57%] Built target freenect-regtest
[ 60%] Built target freenect-tiltdemo
[ 64%] Built target freenect-chunkview
[ 67%] Built target freenect-micview
[ 71%] Built target freenect-hiview
[ 76%] Built target fakenect-record
[ 83%] Built target fakenect
[ 87%] Built target freenect_sync_static
[ 91%] Built target freenect-cpp_pcview
[ 94%] Built target freenect-cppview
[ 96%] Generating freenect3.c
/bin/sh: 1: CYTHON_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND: not found
make[2]: *** [wrappers/python/CMakeFiles/cython3_freenect.dir/build.make:74: wrappers/python/freenect3.c] Error 127
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:712: wrappers/python/CMakeFiles/cython3_freenect.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

I have `Python 3.8.10` installed and I have `cython (0.29.24)`

Comment: Thanks for your post, DunZek! Can you confirm the value and/or existence of `CYTHON_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND` or `CYTHON_EXECUTABLE`? Just with `echo $CYTHON_EXECUTABLE` or `echo $CYTHON_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND`? Thanks.

Comment: Hello @mayosten . Typing `echo $CYTHON_EXECUTABLE` produces an empty line while typing `echo $CYTHON_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND` produces `-NOTFOUND`

Comment: Do you need the python wrapper for this? According to [the docs](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) you can disable the python wrapper with `cmake -DBUILD_PYTHON=OFF` before running `make`.

Comment: Yes I do, making a project on Python. And afterwards, I built it without the Python wrapper anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the help and checking nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `cython3` instead of `cython` so run

```
sudo apt-get install cython3
```

and then to run `cmake` again with the argument

```
-DCYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/cython3
```

probably it ends up as something like this

```
cmake .. -L -DBUILD_PYTHON3=ON -DPython3_EXACTVERSION=3.8.10 -DCYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/cython3
```

Comment: This solved the issue for my installation (and thank you, I'm not sure I could have ever figured this one out before giving up).